# Android SQLite getList issue

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi guys I am new on android development maybe its a easy question but I m stuck on it please help. Its my class. and i cannot cast Uretimyeri to string. How can i do this.

```
    private String Oid;
    private String MalzemeGrubu;
    private String Musteri;
    private UretimYeriBean UretimYeri;
    private String Model;
    private Integer Tipi;
    private Integer Durum;
    private String OzelKod;
    private String Adi;
    private String Kodu;
```

UretimYeriBean is

```
private String Oid;
private Integer Tipi;
private Integer Durum;
private String OzelKod;
private String Adi;
private String Kodu;
```

And here my get list func.

```
 public List<MalzemeBean> getList() {

    List<MalzemeBean> liste = new ArrayList<MalzemeBean>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = Global.DB.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "Select Oid,MalzemeGrubu,Musteri,UretimYeri,Model,Tipi,Durum,OzelKod,Adi,Kodu"
            + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " Order by Ad COLLATE UNICODE";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            MalzemeBean mlz = new MalzemeBean();
            mlz.setOid(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Oid")));
            mlz.setMalzemeGrubu(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("MalzemeGrubu")));
            mlz.setMusteri(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Musteri")));
            mlz.setUretimYeri(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("UretimYeri")));
            mlz.setModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Model")));
            mlz.setTipi(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Tipi")));
            mlz.setDurum(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Durum")));
            mlz.setOzelKod(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("OzelKod")));
            mlz.setAdi(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Adi")));
            mlz.setKodu(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Kodu")));
            liste.add(mlz);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    return liste;
}
```

ıts give me error on

```
mlz.setUretimYeri(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("UretimYeri")));
```

line , and says:

> Error:(57, 46) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted
>   to UretimYeriBean. So how i can convert Uretimyeri.Oid to string

Comment: try doing mlz.setOid(c.getString(String.valueOf(c.getColumnIndex("Oid"))));

Comment: i can set oid with   mlz.setOid(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Oid"))); i need to set setUretimyeri to Uretimyeri's object id

Comment: Store your UretimYeriBean as JSONArray on the databse.and retrive as a jsonarray too.Else it will be complex to handle to save data object class to sqlite  database.

Comment: **SQLLite** or **SQLite** ;) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to set `UretimYeriBean Object` to `mlz.setUretimYeri(.....)`

You're trying to set `String` and that's wrong

```
mlz.setUretimYeri(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("UretimYeri")));
```

### Correct way is

```
mlz.setUretimYeri(new UretimYeriBean(Oid,Tipi,Durum,OzelKod,Adi,Kodu));
```

Comment: Error:(58, 35) error: constructor UretimYeriBean in class UretimYeriBean cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: String,Integer,Integer,String,String,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: @keikoman you should create `constructor` in `UretimYeriBean`

Comment: Anyway i did it . Tyvm MD